# How to configure two ManyToMany relationships and avoid MultipleCascade Problem?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a TableA, TableB and TableC.

Both TableA and TableB have one to many relationships with TableC. Also they have ManyToMany relationship between each other through TableATableB.

```
 public class TableC
 {
     public Guid Id {get;set;}

     public TableA TableA{ get; set; }
     public Guid TableAId { get; set; }

     public TableB TableB{ get; set; }
     public Guid TableBId { get; set; }
 }

public class TableA
{
    public Guid Id { get; set }

    public ICollection<TableATableB> TableATableBs{ get; set; } = [];
    public ICollection<TableC> TableCs { get; set; } = [];

}

public class TableB
{
    public Guid Id { get; set }

    public ICollection<TableATableB> TableATableBs{ get; set; } = [];
    public ICollection<TableC> TableCs { get; set; } = [];

}

 public class TableATableB
 {
     public Guid Id { get; set; }

     public TableA TableA { get; set; }
     public Guid TableAId { get; set; }

     public TableB TableB { get; set; }
     public Guid TableBId { get; set; }

 }
```

**No Fluent API configuration is written**. All the defaults of EfCore migrations. The problem is I'm getting

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_TableCs_TableBs_TableBId' on table 'TableC' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

It will work if I configure Cascade OnDelete to *Restrict* for both TableA, and TableB in the TableC. But I don't want that. I want to TableC to be deleted if any of TableA or TableB are deleted.

Why am I getting this error? Is this because of ManyToMany relationship between TableA and TableB? But logically if any of them get deleted, then it should cascade to the **intermediary** table(TableATableB), and not to the other one...

P.S.
There is some other fields in TableC, so it is a standalone Entity, not used as intermediary for ManyToMany connection between TableA and TableB. I have a dedicated table for that.

Comment: The cycle/multiple cascade paths is not in the shown entities (you can easily verify that by creating test database with just the classes included in the question exactly as they are  - no additional fields/relationships), but in their relationships with some other entities not shown here.